# how to render only a specific part of a partial view?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, partial-views

I am currently working on a **web application** that uses **jquery 1.9.1 and jquery mobile 1.3.2** in visual studio(**MVC4** template).I have many pages where i use a side panel.The side panel has almost same elements in it, so i decided to put it in a partial view,but the elements in the side panel are not exactly same in all the pages.
so i am thinking to put all the elements of side panel used in all the pages in a partial view and **selectively render** them according to the page, i am using.

so is there any way by which i can **render only** selective elements from a partial view?

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to do this using Javascript?.

Lets organize the ideas:

> I have many pages where i use a side panel

What I would do here is to create a layout page that you could use on all the views where you require to add this side panel. So the views you want to render this layout on the final html output should include the following section:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Roles";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_SidePanelLayout.cshtml";
}
```

> so i am thinking to put all the elements of side panel used in all the pages in a partial view and selectively render

Ok I would do the same, however, the rendering of the options, I would not use javascript. I would prefer to send the html of the only required options by sending the models to the view. This is the process I would code:

1-Whenever you request a page that uses this side panel layout, you should fill a ViewBag property (or a model) to pass the page name. So lets say that you have your Home/Index view uses this layout, you can do something like this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
  {
     ViewBag.PageName = "Home-Index"; //you could use constants or enums as best practice
     return View();
  }
```

At some point on your _SidePanelLayout view, I would place a Render Action call. This render action will in fact, render the side panel view with the specific options for that page:

```
@{ Html.RenderAction("GetOptions", "SidePanelController", ViewBag.PageName); }
```

This means that you will require a SidePanelController class with the method that will return your SidePanelView (with the specific options for your the page that you requested):

```
  public class SidePanelController: Controller
    {
      public ActionResult GetOptions(string pageName)
      {
        //you may want to change this List<string> for a list of objects that include
        //the properties you need like url, name, tooltip, etc
        List<string> menuOptions = new List<string>();
        //Determine which options should be rendered
        /* your code */
        //return the view with the filtered options
        return PartialView("_SidePanelView", menuOptions);
      }
    }
```

That way you would have your requirements fullfilled. It's a bit more complex than using javascript, but it's more robust solution.

Hope this helps.